# Does zeroing a drive equivalent to 'Nuke it from orbit'?

Tags: hard-drive, format, dd, malware

Say I have two OS on my computer, one is Windows, and another is Ubuntu.

My Windows apparently has been infected by nasty malware, and it currently making it unusable. However Ubuntu doesn't seem to affected by the occurrence of malware.

People suggest to 'nuke it from orbit'  to banish the malware, I guess this is effective.

If I run `dd if=/dev/zero` to my main hdd, does that also count as `nuke it from orbit`?  will that get rid of malware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `dd if=/dev/zero` to your main hdd, that destroys everything, including the boot sector and *Windows* partitions. That certainly qualifies as [nuking the entire site from orbit](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/nuke-it-from-orbit), but also wipes out your presumably good Ubuntu installation.

In a dual boot system, the surgical removal of an infected Windows partition means deleting the partition and overwriting at least the booting portions with zero. Quick reformatting the Windows partition with your favorite disk utility should be enough to neutralize access to the virus code, but the paranoid will conduct a full overwrite format of that partition will ensure the eradication of the code.

The boot sector may contain a virus, so after erasing the Windows partition, re-install grub2 to freshly write a shiny new boot sector.

There may be BIOS level viruses, but this technique will remove Windows (and therefore any Windows viruses) from your machine.

Answer (score 2):

> If I run dd if=/dev/zero to my main hdd, does that also count as nuke it from orbit? will that get rid of malware?

Yes. Just formatting the windows partition is the SAFER method. `dd` does not care if you tell it to format your Ubuntu partition. gParted used for formatting does: it will not format an active partition.

One more piece of advice: add the empty space to Ubuntu, install virtualBox and install Windows in there. A backup of your complete Windows means to copy the container virtualBox makes. You can then make an automatic backup plan where you keep the last x weeks and fixing your Windows then means deleting the broken one and picking the last good one from a list.